# Android Market: How To Access Traffic Sources Info?

Tags: android, google-play

I have created Android application: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.smsbackupandroid and I have created the site for it: http://www.smsbackupandroid.com/. I am promoting the application by executing SEO project. My goal is to determine how SEO affects the sales at Android Market.

To achieve it I am tracking 'Download' clicks at the site, but the number of such events is not equal to the number of visitors who downloads the application because once the user is redirected from the site to the Android Market - it can leave the product page.

**Question: How can I get information on**

1. How many users actually download the application from Market by clicking 'Download' button at the site.
2. I guess there is no an exact information on traffic sources in Market. So what approach can be utilized to obtain such information?

Answer (score 0):

You can add refferal along with your market url and track the refferal details at install time. sample code for this -

Add following lines in your manifiest

```
    <receiver android:name="com.test.Receiver" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Create a class name anything and override the onReceive of BroadcastReceiver class as follows:

```
     public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
     String referrerString = extras.getString("referrer");

     Log.w("TEST", "Referrer is: " + referrerString);
     }
```